# MongoDB compass simple group by query

Tags: mongodb, nosql, mongodb-compass

How can I run such an SQL query in MongoDB Compass?

```
select subject,count(*) from books group by subject
```

Comment: Please show your schema as well.

Answer (score 4):

you can use [Mongodb Aggregation pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) with [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group) with [$sum](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) to achieve this.

**Try :**

```
db.collection_name.aggregate([{
    $group : {
        _id : "$subject",
        subject : {$first : "$subject"},
        count : {$sum : 1}
    }
}])
```